# Image upload and display on the DOM via Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, filereader, watch

I am trying to write a file-reader directive using AngularJS that will take in images and then push their URL into an array so I can then iterate through that array and draw the images to the DOM.

However, I can't seem to get the needed URL out of the uploaded image in order to call it within an image source tag. Here is what I'm dealing with:

**fileReader directive**

```
app.directive('fileReader', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl:'views/templates/file-reader.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            element.bind("change", function(event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    $rootScope.imageInfo = this.result;
                    $rootScope.$digest(); //digest is required to run with watch?
                    console.log("caught a change");
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            });
        },
        controller: 'UploadController'
    }    
}]);
```

**UploadController**

```
controllers.controller('UploadController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){

    $scope.imageUrls = []; //array of URL

    $rootScope.$watch('imageInfo', function() {
        if ($rootScope.imageInfo) { //if something has been loaded
            console.log("Inside the rootScope watch function");
            $scope.imageUrls.push($rootScope.imageInfo); //add the URL to the array
        }
        $scope.printArray();//to check if the array worked
    });

    $scope.printArray = function(){
        console.log("this is the image URL array:");
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.imageUrls.length; i++){
            console.log($scope.imageUrls[i]);
        };
        console.log("end image url");
    };
}]);
```

**file-reader.html**: `<input type='file' id="files" name="files[]">`

And so originally, I had my `reader.readAsDataURL(file[0])` line outside of the onload block, but it wasn't passing a URL I had pulled via the reader.
However this way the $watch isn't even being activated. Why not?

How can I use this to help pass the URLs of the images from the upload into an array?

(This is all client-side. I realize I'm not actually "uploading" anything beyond the DOM.)

**Update**:
I've fixed the problem of $watch not being called by simply calling a $digest, but I still can't manage to grab the URLs of the data to create an image as opposed to something like: `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh9QC0AOZ0AAwKClNNSpeWloeGhvTXozAqKbe2t0osEMm4r…1pGcsCIoJgiyf8+HPbIGY+OCEjIGhIBw8g8GDcnHgVKnCVCm7BAIooctEhiymDoBHBF4EAADs=`

I rearranged a few of the terms and have updated the code above within the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting objectEquality to true in your $watch function like so:

```
  $rootScope.$watch('imageInfo', function() {
    if ($rootScope.imageInfo) { //if something has been loaded
        console.log("Inside the rootScope watch function");
        $scope.imageUrls.push($rootScope.imageInfo); //add the URL to the array
    }
    $scope.printArray();//to check if the array worked
}, true); // add true here
```

This listens for changes in nested values as well

Also here is a a little article/blog post I found giving a good breakdown and performance of the different $watch mechanisms. May come in handy when deciding which $watch function to use:

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks for the article. However, I managed to fix the $watch problem by just calling $digest--now I'm still stuck with my inability to grab the image URL (not quite an Angular problem,) any chance you can help me solve that part? See my above edits. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a case that the image url is null? what is held in the array after the $watch is invoked?

Comment: It was a number of things; mainly that I didn't realize event.target.files was an array and needed to add [0] to the end. But I have figured it out. Thank you. (: